# How can I differentiate the complex-valued function $|f|$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \ni x\mapsto f(x) \in \mathbb{C}$.
How can I differentiate the function $|f(x)|$ by $x$, namely,
$$
\frac{d}{dx} |f(x)| = \frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{\operatorname{Re} (f(x))^2 + \operatorname{Im}(f(x))^2}?
$$

Comment: Just create two real-valued functions $f_R(x)=\Re(f(x))$ and $f_I(x)=\Im(f(x))$ and apply normal real-valued chain rules.

Comment: Same way you differentiate any other function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$?

Comment: ... though depending on what $f$ looks like, it may (or may not) simplify things to apply the rewriting $$|f(x)|=e^{\Re \log(f(x))}$$

Comment: Oh, thanks everybody. In fact, I'm wondering the inequality $\frac{d}{dx}|f(x)| \le c |\frac{d}{dx}f(x)|$ (for some positive constant $c$) holds or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=f_r(x)+if_i(x)$, where $f_r$ and $f_i$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f$, respectively.

Then, $|f(x)|=\sqrt{f_r^2(x)+f_i^2(x)}$ and

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{d|f(x)|}{dx}=\frac{f_r(x)f_r'(x)+f_i(x)f_i'(x)}{|f(x)|}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can I derive some kind of relationship between $\frac{d}{dx}|f(x)|$ and $|\frac{d}{dx}f(x)|$ some thing like $\frac{d}{dx}|f(x)| \le constant*|\frac{d}{dx}f(x)|$?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  To your new question, the short answer is no, not in general.  Recall $|\frac{df}{dx}|=\sqrt{f_r'^2+f_i'^2}$ and that does not have a general relationship to $\frac{d|f|}{dx}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, however, I think $$ |d|f|/dx| \le \frac{|f_r f_r'| +|f_i f_i'|}{|f|} \le \frac{(|f_r| + |f_i|)(|f_r'| + |f_i'|)}{|f|} \le c \frac{|f| |f'|}{|f|} $$ Did I do some mistakes here?